# KSQLDB-UDAF: how to pass schema parameter struct

Tags: java, gradle, user-defined-functions, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

I'm new for KSQLDB. I would like to create the UDAF with struct parameter. and I follow the instruction of this document https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/create-a-user-defined-function/.

I can build jar without error but when calling this function. it shows this error:

```
ksql> SELECT a, stats(b) AS stats FROM s4 GROUP BY a EMIT CHANGES;
Function 'stats' does not accept parameters (STRUCT<C BIGINT>).
Valid alternatives are:
-----------------
ksql> DESCRIBE FUNCTION stats;

Name        : STATS
Author      : example user
Version     : 1.3.5
Overview    : Maintains statistical values.
Type        : AGGREGATE
Jar         : /etc/ksqldb/ext/udf-0.0.1.jar
Variations  :
```

```html
package io.confluent.developer;

import io.confluent.ksql.function.udaf.Udaf;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udaf.UdafDescription;
import io.confluent.ksql.function.udaf.UdafFactory;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;

@UdafDescription(name = "stats",
                 author = "example user",
                 version = "1.3.5",
                 description = "Maintains statistical values.")
public class StatsUdaf {

    public static final Schema PARAM_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().optional()
        .field("C", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    public static final String PARAM_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR = "STRUCT<" +
        "C BIGINT" +
        ">";

    public static final Schema AGGREGATE_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().optional()
        .field("MIN", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .field("MAX", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .field("COUNT", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    public static final String AGGREGATE_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR = "STRUCT<" +
        "MIN BIGINT," +
        "MAX BIGINT," +
        "COUNT BIGINT" +
        ">";

    public static final Schema RETURN_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().optional()
        .field("MIN", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .field("MAX", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .field("COUNT", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .field("DIFFERENTIAL", Schema.OPTIONAL_INT64_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    public static final String RETURN_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR = "STRUCT<" +
        "MIN BIGINT," +
        "MAX BIGINT," +
        "COUNT BIGINT," +
        "DIFFERENTIAL BIGINT" +
        ">";

    private StatsUdaf() {
    }

    @UdafFactory(description = "Computes the min, max, count, and difference between min/max.",
                 paramSchema = PARAM_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR,
                 aggregateSchema = AGGREGATE_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR,
                 returnSchema = RETURN_SCHEMA_DESCRIPTOR)
    public static Udaf<Struct, Struct, Struct> createUdaf() {
        return new StatsUdafImpl();
    }

    private static class StatsUdafImpl implements Udaf<Struct, Struct, Struct> {

        @Override
        public Struct initialize() {
            return new Struct(AGGREGATE_SCHEMA);
        }

        @Override
        public Struct aggregate(Struct newValue, Struct aggregateValue) {
            long c = newValue.getInt64("C");

            long min = Math.min(c, getMin(aggregateValue));
            long max = Math.max(c, getMax(aggregateValue));
            long count = (getCount(aggregateValue) + 1);

            aggregateValue.put("MIN", min);
            aggregateValue.put("MAX", max);
            aggregateValue.put("COUNT", count);

            return aggregateValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Struct map(Struct intermediate) {
            Struct result = new Struct(RETURN_SCHEMA);

            long min = intermediate.getInt64("MIN");
            long max = intermediate.getInt64("MAX");

            result.put("MIN", min);
            result.put("MAX", max);
            result.put("COUNT", intermediate.getInt64("COUNT"));
            result.put("DIFFERENTIAL", max - min);

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public Struct merge(Struct aggOne, Struct aggTwo) {
            return aggOne;
        }

        private Long getMin(Struct aggregateValue) {
            Long result = aggregateValue.getInt64("MIN");

            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            } else {
                return Long.MAX_VALUE;
            }
        }

        private Long getMax(Struct aggregateValue) {
            Long result = aggregateValue.getInt64("MAX");

            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            } else {
                return Long.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }

        private Long getCount(Struct aggregateValue) {
            Long result = aggregateValue.getInt64("COUNT");

            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            } else {
                return 0L;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to resolve it. Thanks you so much.